# How to span background color to the whole window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to set a background color for the whole window. It was supposed to span the whole window. But it covers only the line which has "Hello World". The remaining background is white. Can anybody help me with this? I have tried with the following codes (found in internet) but it doesn't work for me.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="bg">Hello World</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-color: grey;

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

index.css:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: change `height: 100%;` of `html, body` to `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: it didn't work but changing the .bg height to height: 100vh or min-height: 100vh worked. I don't understand the reason though.

Comment: `100%` give a full height of a parent. but it will not be a full window height if the parent is not full height. by giving it `min-height: 100vh` you give it a full viewport height even if the parent height is less then full viewport height

Comment: If `.bg` is a direct child of `body` then it should work as you have it.

Comment: Oh. It isn't, I see. It's being rendered inside `#root`. Make sure,  then, that `#root` also has its  height  set to 100%.

Comment: A percentage height on an element only works when it's parent has an explicit height. If it doesn't, it's ignored and you get an automatic height, defined by the size of its content.